# Repeated columns a into new row

Tags: r, spread

I have repeated values in column a and I want these to become new row with information from column b.

I've tried the tidyr function for gather and spread

```
library("tidyr")
rearrangeddf<-spread(df,a,b)


#Input
a=c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B")
b=c(1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13214634,14,15432)
df=data.frame(a,b)

#Output
x=c("A",1,2,3,4,5)
y=c("B",11,12,13214634,14,1543)
rearrangeddf=rbind(x,y)
```

> Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
>   Keys are shared for 10 rows:
>   * 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
>   * 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
>   Do you need to create unique ID with tibble::rowid_to_column()?
>   Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); library(tidyr); df %>%group_by(a) %>% mutate(new = row_number()) %>% spread(new, b)`

Comment: `split(df$b, df$a)`

Comment: @jogo Nice! To complete `do.call(rbind, split(df$b, df$a))`

Comment: `c("A",1,2,3,4,5)` is identical with `c("A", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5")` because of coercion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
aggregate(b~a, df, c)
  a      b.1      b.2      b.3      b.4      b.5
1 A        1        2        3        4        5
2 B       11       12 13214634       14    15432
```

**Not part of answer**

Do not use `c=c("A",1,2,3,4,5)` because this will overwrite the `c()` function. See here:

```
c=c("A",1,2,3,4,5)
aggregate(b~a, df, c)
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Comment: Is that `c` the concatenate? Or `c` your vector. Don't use pre-defined functions to name objects

Comment: @Sotos This is exactly what I am saying. `c=c("A",1,2,3,4,5)` is taken from the question and warn using this assigment

Comment: @schwantke I don't understand what does "c" mean here? In my example, it was used to generate the output df (which doesn't exist), I'm unsure do you mean concatenate? It doesn't work with the code.

Comment: @Marcosullivan `c()` is a [function in r](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/c). You shoud not assign objects to pre-defined funtions. So rather don't use `c=c("A",1,2,3,4,5)`. Besides, if the answer(s) answer your question, you can upvote and/ or mark as answered

Comment: @Marcosullivan the code `a=c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B");
b=c(1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13214634,14,15432);
df=data.frame(a,b);aggregate(b~a, df, c)` works but only as long as you have not run `c=c("A",1,2,3,4,5)` before. Because otherwise you overwrite the function `c()`

Comment: Great thanks @schwantke I have edited the output file to correct this, and will not do this in future datasets.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"),
              b=c(1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13214634,14,15432))
t(unstack(df, b ~ a))
# > t(unstack(df, b ~ a))
#   [,1] [,2]     [,3] [,4]  [,5]
# A    1    2        3    4     5
# B   11   12 13214634   14 15432
```

Comment: I had something similiar first, using `aggregate(b~a, df, c)[ , -1]` but then I saw that in the expected output `A B` are in first column

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @jogo, but "A" and "B" become the row name with this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Sotos this worked perfectly

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%group_by(a) %>% mutate(new = row_number()) %>% spread(new, b)
```